# Web page still visible after stopping Apache

Tags: apache2

I have Apache running on Ubuntu Server. After stopping Apache with `sudo service apache2 stop`, the web page is still accessible for some reason.

`pgrep apache` gets no results so it is definitely stopped.

edit:

`sudo lsof -i tcp:80 | egrep LISTEN` output:

```
nginx   25348     root    6u  IPv4 6658395      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25348     root    8u  IPv6 6658397      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25349 www-data    6u  IPv4 6658395      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25349 www-data    8u  IPv6 6658397      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25350 www-data    6u  IPv4 6658395      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25350 www-data    8u  IPv6 6658397      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25351 www-data    6u  IPv4 6658395      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25351 www-data    8u  IPv6 6658397      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25352 www-data    6u  IPv4 6658395      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   25352 www-data    8u  IPv6 6658397      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a different web server installed and running.  Some common web servers used on Ubuntu are Apache, Tom Cat and Nginx.

You can check to see which is currently listening on the web port with:

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:80 | egrep LISTEN
```

Most likely the culprit will be `nginx1`, which will be indentified by the results similar to:

```
nginx   28487     root    6u  IPv4 603899449      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   28487     root    7u  IPv6 603899450      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   28488 www-data    6u  IPv4 603899449      0t0  TCP *:http    (LISTEN)
nginx   28488 www-data    7u  IPv6 603899450      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

To avoid confusion you should disable all but your preferred web server.  Having more than one will make it hard to know which server the pages are being sent to.

Comment: Yeah I do have another nginx server running. But the nginx server is only being used as a reverse proxy for some nodejs applications. The site that is being served is the site that only Apache is configured to serve, Nginx is not configured to serve this page anywhere.

Comment: Will you add the output of this to your question: `sudo lsof -i tcp:80 | egrep LISTEN`

Comment: Done, but I don't know how nginx could possibly be serving this folder, I only configured this folder with Apache. Nowhere in my nginx configurations do I have anything that references the directory it is serving.

Comment: Okay wait, I should have also added that the Apache server is not serving on port 80, I have it on 4001. doing that command you said before but with the port 4001 I now get a bunch of apache2 processes

Comment: You can verify that it's serving the page that you are seeing by stopping the service.  After you do this, this will answer your question as to why the page is visible after stopping Apache.  The page is being served by Nginx.

Comment: I did stop nginx, it is still being served

Comment: Also I just stopped all those apache2 processes I mentioned earlier but the page is still being served

Comment: Run the `lsof` on the port where the page is being served so that you can see what application is serving it.  Apache and Nginx are not the only applications that can serve a web page.  Whatever is serving it should appear in the `lsof` command.

Comment: Like I said, I already did that. Read my previous comments. I stopped all the processes that showed when using lsof on port 4001. Still nothing.

Comment: You previously said using **4001** for the port showed Apache.  Does it still show Apache?  Or is the output blank.  If it's not, will you add the output to your queston?  Also, can you show what is typed in your browser (you can use `www.test.com` for the site name) when you call up the page?